Unable to create stored procedure through Azure pipeline
I am trying to create a stored procedure through Azure pipeline, however I did not succeed.
Here is my script:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ROUTINE_NAME 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
               WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'sp_checknpapermission' 
                 AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
BEGIN
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    EXEC('
          CREATE PROCEDURE sp_checknpapermission
          AS
          BEGIN
              SET NOCOUNT ON;
              DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(128);
              DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR
                SELECT name
                FROM sys.database_principals
                WHERE name LIKE '%@web.onmicrosoft.com' AND type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER';

              BEGIN TRY
                OPEN user_cursor;
                FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @UserName;

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT 1
                   FROM sys.database_role_members AS rm
                   JOIN sys.database_principals AS r ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
                   JOIN sys.database_principals AS u ON rm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
                   WHERE u.name = @UserName  AND r.name = 'db_owner'
                )
                BEGIN
                     PRINT 'The user ' + @UserName + ' does not have db_owner role';
                     END
                     ELSE
                     BEGIN
                        PRINT 'The user ' + @UserName + ' already has the db_owner role';
                     END
                     FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @UserName;
                END

               CLOSE user_cursor;
               DEALLOCATE user_cursor;
             END TRY
             BEGIN CATCH
                 ROLLBACK;
                 PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
            END CATCH;
    END
  ')
END

This is the error I get:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server sqlserver-rba-dev, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near '%'.

Any idea what is wrong here?

FYI the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

As for the error, it is telling your the problem. You don't appear to be be escaping your single quotes properly. Why, however, aren't you just using CREATE OR ALTER? There's no need for the syntax you use anymore; all supported versions of SQL Server support CREATE OR ALTER and you're on Azure SQL Database.

@ThomA, this works when i run directly on ssms.  but failing when i run through pipeline

I can assure you, that above code will not work in SSMS, I was so confident it was invalid syntax I tested it; it failed. It also doesn't run correctly in a db<>fiddle. Again, why aren't you use CREATE OR ALTER?

in ssms , executed script starts from Create Procedure.  but in actual script i have else block as well, if store procedure is exist it alter the existing one, if not it creates new one.  i posted only create block

So you aren't using CREATE OR ALTER because...? Why are you using SQL Server 2014 and prior syntax?

In Script i am using CREATE PROCEDURE right ? and Else block it will be ALTER PROCEDURE.  if you take Script from
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_xxxxx, you would be able to run in ssms

As thom wrote, every quote inside EXEC('...') must be doubled. For example: select 'test' would become: EXEC('SELECT ''Test''')

so should i change WHERE name LIKE '%@raboweb.onmicrosoft.com' AND type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER';  to 'WHERE name LIKE ''%@raboweb.onmicrosoft.com'' AND type_desc = ''EXTERNAL_USER''';

Yeah, i wrote every quote

" i am using CREATE PROCEDURE right ? and Else block it will be ALTER PROCEDURE" that doesn't answer why you aren't using CREATE OR ALTER.

The error is telling you the problem, you do have syntax errors in your code; many syntax errors.
In truth, there's no need for the syntax you are using (checking the proc exists and then executing the CREATE in a deferred batch). All supported versions so SQL Server permit the CREATE OR ALTER syntax, and you are using Azure SQL Database, which is based on the latest version of the data engine (and sometimes the next one).
So just use CREATE OR ALTER (and get rid of the sp_ prefix):
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.checknpapermission
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(128);
    DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name
        FROM sys.database_principals
        WHERE name LIKE '%@web.onmicrosoft.com'
          AND type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER';

    BEGIN TRY
        OPEN user_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor
        INTO @UserName;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM sys.database_role_members rm
                                JOIN sys.database_principals r ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
                                JOIN sys.database_principals u ON rm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
                           WHERE u.name = @UserName
                             AND r.name = 'db_owner') BEGIN
                PRINT 'The user ' + @UserName + ' does not have db_owner role';
            END;
            ELSE BEGIN
                PRINT 'The user ' + @UserName + ' already has the db_owner role';
            END;
            FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor
            INTO @UserName;
        END;

        CLOSE user_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE user_cursor;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK; --Why is this here...?
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH;
END;

Better yet, as well, bin that CURSOR; it'll be awfully slow. We can also get rid of the TRY...CATCH and ROLLBACK (what are you attempt to roll back here?), and PRINTing errors is an anti-pattern You can easily achieve the same results with some simple string aggregation.
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.checknpapermission
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PrintStatement varchar(8000),
            @LF char(1) = CHAR(10)

    SELECT @PrintStatement = STRING_AGG('The user ' + u.name + ' ' + CASE WHEN r.principal_id IS NULL THEN 'does not have the db_owner role'
                                                                          ELSE 'already has the db_owner role' END, @LF)
    FROM sys.database_principals u
         LEFT JOIN sys.database_role_members rm
              JOIN sys.database_principals r ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
                                             AND r.name = 'db_owner'
                                             ON u.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
    WHERE u.name LIKE '%@web.onmicrosoft.com'
      AND u.type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER';

    PRINT @PrintStatement;

END;


Ok, i tried the above one through ssms and able to create SP, but when i execute it it does not display list of users with the roles

I gave it a go in my sandbox database, and it worked as expected, @rameshreddy . Same in a db<>fiddle. If you aren't getting any results, that implies there are no users in the database that fulfil the WHERE in your database.

Thank you @Thom A,   you made it very simple and working as expected. thank you so much.
